# write a sql to show data by minute ，and show null when there is no data in some minutes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

here is an original data table：

```
DeviceNo     Datetime              Data
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:51.120     520
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:52.320     521
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:53.510     526
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:54.420     528
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:55.380     539
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:01.860     560
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:02.310     561
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:05.520     562
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:06.125     565
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:07.723     569
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:08.920     591
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:09.250     596
```

I want to write a sql to get result as follow:

```
DeviceNo Datetime               Data
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:51     520
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:52     521
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:53     526
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:54     528
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:55     539
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:56     null
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:57     null
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:58     null
12345   2015-08-01 01:25:59     null
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:00     null
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:01     560
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:02     561
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:03     null
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:04     null
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:05     562
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:06     565
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:07     569
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:08     591
12345   2015-08-01 01:26:09     596
```

I write a sql to show data by minute ,and show null when  there is no data in some minutes as below result table.
thanks.

Comment: Did you try the solution that I suggested..

Comment: could you please try it in fiddle and check whether the running result of your sql is corresponding with the result table given below，thanks.

Comment: You will need to modify the code a little bit to suit your purpose. But it is a good starting point. Let me know if you face any problems. If you can set up fiddle with sample data maybe I can provide a working query.

Comment: sorry！there was something wrong with the original data，and I have corrected it.the datetime of records is continuous by minute.please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate data for every minute for device no and left join it with your original table, to get the expected result. You can generate data using recursive cte.

Example:

```
 WITH dates AS (
     SELECT CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATETIME) 'date'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, t.date) 
       FROM dates t
      WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, t.date) < '2015-02-01')
SELECT * from dates
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Note: you might want to clip milliseconds from your original table in order to join